# Uploaded image Not Showing Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I create a file uploads capabilities in Symfony2 using the code examples provided by the documentation in Symfony website

```
 public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
   // return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}
```

I can upload a file but twig cant display it

```
  <td><img src="/uploads/documents/{{ task.path }}" id="img-responsive">    </td>
```

Inspecting with Google's developer tool shows the correct link of the image

```
<img src="/uploads/documents/Desert.jpg" id="img-responsive">
```

Copying the image url to a browser show

```
   Object not found
   404
```

How would you display an image uploaded in Symfony in a situation like this?

```
   app
   src
   web
     bundles
     uploads
       documents


     return __DIR__.'/../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
```

**Update**

The path is save in database

```
    path          id
    Desert.jpg     1
    cat.jpg        2
    dog.jpg        3
```

Comment: you should really be using twigs `{{ asset() }}` method.  Then use the path and filename in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DevDonkey suggestion, or you can change your code like this

```
 <td><img src="yourhost.com/web/uploads/documents/{{ task.path }}" id="img-responsive">    </td>
```

This should work as I tried it and used it in my current project..